# How to extract the trailing digits from a string in R?

Tags: r, string, character

I have a column of data that looks like this:

```
**varX**

Q1#_1

Q1#_5

Q1#_10
```

I would like to edit the data to look like this:

```
**varX**

1

5

10
```

Is there a command I could use to simply keep all information after the underscore?

Comment: you can use `gsub(".*_(\\d+)", "\\1", df$varX)`It'll work even if your pattern at the beginning of your string changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you always have the Q1#_ string, you can do:

```
gsub("Q1#_", "", df$varX)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a `tidyverse` solution, you can use `str_extract` from the `stringr` package:

```
data %>% 
mutate(varx = str_extract(varx, "[0-9]+$")) %>%
mutate(varx = as.numeric(varx)) # include this last line if you want a number and not character
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for `sub`, substitute a certain part of a string with something else. You can give it a regular expression if you want to go fancy, or just give it a literal:

```
VarX <- sub('Q1#_', '', VarX, fixed=T)
```

The fancy way ("remove everything before and including the underscore") would be

```
VarX <- sub('^.*_', '', VarX)
```

And you may want to convert it to a numeric or an integer:

```
VarX <- as.integer(sub('Q1#_', '', VarX, fixed=T)) # or as.numeric
```

Answer (score 0):

You could you use *regular expressions*:

```
df[["varX"]] <- sub(".+_", "", df[["varX"]])
df
  varX
1    1
2    5
3   10
```

Or *regular expressions-free:* with `strsplit()`:

```
df[["varX"]] <- sapply(df[["varX"]], function(x) strsplit(x, "_")[[c(1,2)]])
```